# An invalid character was found in the mail header: 'è'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, smtpclient

I am sending an email using SMTP mail client in asp.net mvc application. When i send an email it throws exception if the email has extended Ascii characters.
The exception is **An invalid character was found in the mail header: 'è'.**

Can you please help me to accept the unicode characters in email?

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: make sure your encoding is UTF-8 .

Answer (score 0):

```
 mail.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```

Comment: Exception is in to address. i have set mail.HeaderEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
But no use. can you please let me know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I received this error when  if this is modified to "network" --- then error got resolved. ( My understanding is - Incase of specified pickupdirectory option, the header -encoding utf-8 (base64) was giving error )

Hope it helps